# Laravel Unit Test Class Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5, composer-php

```
<?php 

use App\Repositories\APIModels\SalesError as SalesError;
use App\Repositories\APIModels\Sales as Sales;

class SalesErrorTest extends \TestCase {

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testCreate()
    {
        $sales_error = new SalesError;
        $sales_error->sale_id = 5;
        $sales_error->error_type = 3;
        $sales_error->description = 'Unknown error occured';
        $sales_error->resolved_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $this->assertTrue($sales_error->save());
    }

    public function testRelation()
    {
        $sales = Sales::find(45)->errors();
        var_dump($sales);
    }
}
```

In the above test when i run `testCreate` it works fine. But when i run other method it says

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SalesError' not found in
>   /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
>   on line 878

**Sales Model**

```
   /**
     * Has Many relation with SalesError
     * 
     * @return object
     */
    public function errors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('SalesError', 'sale_id', 'sale_id');
    }
```

**Sales Error Model**

```
  /**
     * Has many to one relation with Sales Model
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function sales()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('Sales', 'sale_id');
    }
```

Comment: Could you show your SalesError and Sales models please? Just to see how you set up the relationships

Comment: I updated my code in question. Please have a look

Comment: I removed all the name spaces from my Models and now its working fine. But i don't understandy why ? I want to put namespace in it acutally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the full `namespace` to the relationships.

Also, you are missing the `return` statement at the `sales` relationship.

```
public function errors()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Repositories\APIModels\SalesError', 'sale_id', 'sale_id');
    // or
    return $this->hasMany(SalesError::class, 'sale_id', 'sale_id');
}

public function sales()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Sales::class, 'sale_id');
}
```